# Sublime Text Bulk Line Delete

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

How do delete to line?

But example [//] I want to delete the post of the line .

```
$TEXT['cover-upload-success'] = "Kapak fotoğrafı başarıyla yüklendi.";
// $TEXT['cover-upload-success'] = "Обложка успешно загружена!";
// $TEXT['cover-upload-success'] = "Обкладинка успішно завантажена!";
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What exactly are you trying to delete? Please show a clear example of where your cursor is (using the `|` symbol), and what you want your text to look like after you've deleted the text. The phrases "*How do delete to line?*" and "*delete the post of the line*" do not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your question should be more clear, however I am answering on the presumption that you simply want to select all commented out line (`//`) from you file.

1. Find `//` with `Ctrl + F` (Win) or `Cmd + F` (Mac)
2. Find all by clicking on the button or hitting `Alt + Enter` (Win) or `Cmd + Enter`
3. Now with multiple cursors, you can select all the lines with `Ctrl + L` (Win) or `Cmd + L`.
4. Hit `Del`

**However** you really shouldn't delete commented out code in general.

Please reword your question if you wanted to accomplish something else.